# Asp.net Core Restrict (prevent) multiple login

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identity, multiple-login

I am using asp.net core identity to login.

```
    await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

I want to restrict same user from multiple logins from different devices or places. Whats the way?

I also read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47438488/prevent-multiple-login-in-asp-net-core-2) but did not get any results

Comment: Are you looking for some built-in feature? I'm not aware of any. What I'd do is to extend the user entity with a bool flag that indicates if the user is logged in (setting it to true during login), and manually prevent logins if it's true. Probably through some abstraction (proxy) over SignInManager. What is your requirement for log outs? Could a user just call log out on a new device and then instantly call log in? Or do you want to allow log outs only on the previously allowed device (e.g. by requiring a valid or expired token to be presented)?

Comment: This also brings up the question of how do you identify the devices. Because, if you use tokens, then non-naive users could possibly copy that token to another device.

Comment: I can see a terrible issue when the user loses his access to the logged-in device and could not log in using a new device :) - Anyway this feature is possible for almost normal users but I think it's really hard to guard against super-users or experts who may want to break it.